# Google Sheets: VLOOKUP with wildcard search

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, wildcard

I have the following formula in my main sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="", "", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B
, Reference!A:B, 2, FALSE), "Unknown")))
```

This works if there's an exact match ("equals") between the main sheet value and one of the values of column A on the Reference sheet.

However, I want it to be able to do a wildcard search - if the value of the Reference contains wildcards.

Example (the column Catagory shows the **result** I want the formula to give):

**Main sheet:**

```
Text           | Catagory (Ideally) 
---------------+--------------------

House          | Houses     
House Post     | Unknown            
PreHouse       | Unknown        
PreHouse Post  | Unknown

Dog2#          | Dogs
Dog2# Post     | Dogs       
PreDog2#       | Unknown
PreDog2# Post  | Unknown

Bird           | Birds
Bird Post      | Birds
PreBird        | Birds
PreBird Post   | Birds

Something Else | Unknown
```

**Reference Sheet:**

```
SearchTerm  | FoundCatagory
------------+----------------
House       | Houses
Dog*        | Dogs
*Bird*      | Birds
```

Can you please help?

(This relates to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067998/google-sheets-vlookup-to-do-contains-instead-of-equals/77068240#77068240) - thanks for the help there!)

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(D:D,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+tocol(map(A:A,B:B,lambda(a,b,if(ifna(xmatch(a,Σ,2)),b,))),1),"Unknown"))))
```

[image]