# Google sheets Arrayformula with Vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a formula in Google Sheets that automatically updates when a new row is added (we're using Zapier to add new transactions to a spreadsheet and it adds the new data after the last non-empty row).

I use ArrayFormula to automatically perform the function when a new row is added. The following formula with ArrayFormula and Vlookup works for a simple lookup:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($B2:B),"",VLOOKUP($A2:A,Lookups!B3:D17,3,TRUE)))
```

I'm now trying to categorize more complex text. This formula works correctly for a single cell:

```
=VLOOKUP(MATCH(TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Lookups!$F$3:$F$33,B2))), 0),Lookups!$A$3:$J$33,7)
```

However, when I add the ArrayFormula function to automatically perform the function when a new row is added, it only provides the correct result for the first row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($B$2:B),"",VLOOKUP(ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Lookups!$F$3:$F$33,$B$2:B))), 0)),Lookups!$A$3:$J$33,7)))
```

Is Match not compatible with ArrayFormula? Is there an alternative function to Match that will work with ArrayFormula?

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform). (PS it doesn't make sense to nest ARRAYFORMULAs, it's sufficient to have one on the outside)

Comment: See this file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15udvPg2vRSE_k6tfXAw54vam79b9pUpOr37ZWVqzJ6E/edit#gid=0

Comment: Your question should stand on its own. The purpose of the functions, the data being accessed, and so on should be explained in the body of the question. The question should also include a sample of the outcome that you are trying to achieve. Please don't expect that users must/will/can/should open you spreadsheet to understand the question. Also, please consider including your sample data as text within the body of the question. There are many ways to build markdown tables including the free online service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to [Google Sheets: VLOOKUP with wildcard search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77072740/1330560), answer by @rockinfreakshow.

The following solution is an adaptation:

Enter this formula in Sheet1, cell C2:

```
=map(
 B2:B,
  lambda(
   Σ,
   if(Σ="",,
    iferror(
     +tocol(
      map(
       Lookups!F3:F9,
       lambda(
        a,
        if(ifna(xmatch("*"&a&"*",Σ,2)),a,)
       )
      )
     ,1)
    ,"")
   )
  )
)
```

---

**RESULTS**

[image: results]

---

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks so much!

Comment: I hope you will “accept” the answer. And hat-tip to  @rockinfreakshow.